# PhantomJS add more than 1 cookie to the request

Tags: javascript, cookies, phantomjs

I am having trouble adding more than 1 cookie to a request, this is my javascript for 1 cookie:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

phantom.addCookie({

  'name'     : 'TestCookie_Name_201312174009',   /* required property */
  'value'    : 'TestCookie_Value_164009',  /* required property */
  'domain'   : 'www.miau.com',        /* required property */
  'path'     : '/',
  'httponly' : true,
  'secure'   : false,
  'expires'  : (new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60)   /* <-- expires in 1 hour */
});



page.open('http://www.miau.com', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //page.render('google.png');
        phantom.exit();
    }, 200);
});
```

And I launch it through proxy to see the request:

`phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --disk-cache=true --proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8080  --web-security=false  test.js`

The cookie is added fine, but then I try 2 cookies:

And it doesn't work, I have also tried this other option, treating it like a list

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

phantom.addCookie([{

  'name'     : 'TestCookie_Name_201312174009',   /* required property */
  'value'    : 'TestCookie_Value_164009',  /* required property */
  'domain'   : 'www.miau.com',        /* required property */
  'path'     : '/',
  'httponly' : true,
  'secure'   : false,
  'expires'  : (new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60)   /* <-- expires in 1 hour */
}
,
{
  'name'     : 'TestCookie_Name_2',   /* required property */
  'value'    : 'TestCookie_Value_2',  /* required property */
  'domain'   : 'www.miau.com',        /* required property */
  'path'     : '/',
  'httponly' : true,
  'secure'   : false,
  'expires'  : (new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60)   /* <-- expires in 1 hour */
}]);
```

But again, I don't manage to get it working....

Another thing I have tried is this:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

phantom.addCookie({

  'name'     : 'TestCookie_Name_201312174009',   /* required property */
  'value'    : 'TestCookie_Value_164009',  /* required property */
  'domain'   : 'www.miau.com',        /* required property */
  'path'     : '/',
  'httponly' : true,
  'secure'   : false,
  'expires'  : (new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60)   /* <-- expires in 1 hour */
});

phantom.addCookie({

  'name'     : 'TestCookie_Name_2',   /* required property */
  'value'    : 'TestCookie_Value_2',  /* required property */
  'domain'   : 'www.miau.com',        /* required property */
  'path'     : '/',
  'httponly' : true,
  'secure'   : false,
  'expires'  : (new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60)   /* <-- expires in 1 hour */
});

page.open('http://www.miau.com', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //page.render('google.png');
        phantom.exit();
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: Can you try: `phantom.cookies = [ /* your cookie objects */ ];` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a look at the PhantomJS Docs:

> `addCookie(Object) {Boolean}`
>
> *Introduced: PhantomJS 1.7*
>
> Add a Cookie to the CookieJar. Returns `true` if successfully added,
>   otherwise `false`.

It's not referring to more than one cookie(s). So looking at `phantom.cookies` which is the variable, that holds the cookiejar - we find the following:

> `phantom.cookies {Object[]}`
>
> *Introduced: PhantomJS 1.7*
>
> Get or set Cookies for any domain (though, for setting, use of
>   phantom.addCookie is preferred). These Cookies are stored in the
>   CookieJar and will be supplied when opening pertinent WebPages.
>
> This array will be pre-populated by any existing Cookie data stored in
>   the cookie file specified in the PhantomJS startup config/command-line
>   options, if any.

The documentation quote above, tells us, that the cookies variable, inside the phantom object, is an object array. So it must be possible to assign more than one.
By having a quick look at the tests, we notice, there is a test for assigning multiple cookies - see referenced code lines from `github`:

[Cookies Array](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/test/module/cookiejar/cookiejar.js#L25)

[Cookies Array gets assigned](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/test/module/cookiejar/cookiejar.js#L73)

Basically that tells us, that it is possible to assign more than one cookie by simply call:

```
phantom.cookies = [{

  'name'     : 'TestCookie_Name_201312174009',   /* required property */
  'value'    : 'TestCookie_Value_164009',  /* required property */
  'domain'   : 'www.miau.com',        /* required property */
  'path'     : '/',
  'httponly' : true,
  'secure'   : false,
  'expires'  : (new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60)   /* <-- expires in 1 hour */
}
,
{
  'name'     : 'TestCookie_Name_2',   /* required property */
  'value'    : 'TestCookie_Value_2',  /* required property */
  'domain'   : 'www.miau.com',        /* required property */
  'path'     : '/',
  'httponly' : true,
  'secure'   : false,
  'expires'  : (new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60)   /* <-- expires in 1 hour */
}];
```

Comment: Dude, That Worked, I can only say: thatwasepic! ;)